# Tabela/Campo para preço de produtos no Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Em qual tabela/campo ficam armazenados os preços dos produtos cadastrados no Magento 1.9?

Vi em alguns sites a tabela `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, mas não vi o campo `price` ou qualquer outro que pareça um valor em R$.

ATUALIZANDO: Essa é realmente a tabela com os preços. O problema é que eu preciso usar uma conversão para o valor aparecer corretamente, mas sobre este assunto, estou zero! Alguém pode dar uma luz?

Comment: Quando tenho problemas desse tipo, coloco um valor absurdo (tipo `R$ 939393,93`) e faço uma busca no PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Cara! Solução simples e objetiva. Hahaha. Vou fazer aqui e retorno!

Comment: Certo, achei a tabela. O problema é que não consigo achar um campo de referência em todas, para montar meu relatório. Alguém já fez algo do tipo? Preciso das imagens, SKU, Quantidade e Valor. De todos os campos, apenas o valor não está batendo.

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta com novos dados, desse jeito ela vai parar na página principal e receberá novas visualizações

Comment: Obrigado @brasofilo. Ainda sou meio novo por aqui...

Answer (score 2):

O Magento utiliza uma estrutura de dados chamada EAV, entity attribute value ou entidade atributo valor.

Ou seja, você tem uma entidade, que possui um atributo que possui um valor.

Para você encontrar o atributo preço, terá que olhar os atributos na tabela `eav_attribute`, o atributo `special_price` tem um `id` que o conectará com `catalog_product_entity_decimal` através do `attribute_id` aonde está armazenado o valor.

O EAV permite moldar qualquer tipo de dados dinâmicamente é útil para ecommerces.